# How do you solve this infinite series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Hey I'm a 8th grader and stumbled upon this problem.
$$\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{m!x^{m-2n}i^{2n}}{(2n)!(m-2n)!}$$
Now I noticed a lot of of similarities with the standard form of binomial theorem. The problem I stumbled upon while playing with the "cos'th" derivative of a polynomial.
$$cos(\frac{d}{dx})x^m$$
Now I finally found the answer to this after using the complex definition of cosine but I was wondering how you would do the infinite series on the top . Thanks! and sorry for the broken English, English isn't my first language .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 8th grader?? Which country? Wow. Well tjos is expansion of the binomial theorem. Check the answer below

Comment: Im from Indonesia

Answer (score 2):

Hint: starting with the binomial theorem
$$
(x+y)^m = \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{m!x^{m-k}y^k}{k!(m-k)!},
$$
plug in $y=i$ and $y=-i$.

Comment: thx I figured it out